# Windows xp sp3 not legal after 3 years

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have had this computer about 3years and recently got a message from Microsoft stating that I have a bogus product key. When I try to correct this by going online and purchase akey to be complient it says xp is no longer available. Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: Sorry, but it needs to be asked: do you have a valid key that you purchased from Microsoft?

Comment: Have you verified the message is from Microsoft directly and not a scam of some sort?

Comment: If you have the original license, you should be able to call the Microsoft Activation Hotline and explain your case, and they can reactivate your Windows. If it wasn't a valid license to begin with, then well, I guess you were lucky to make it this far.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/?ln=en-gb&c2=1173), mainstream support for Windows XP ended in 2009, but they offer extended support till 2014.
What I understand by that is that you can't buy serials for XP anymore, but if you have one, it'll be supported till 2014. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on what I should do?

It will continue to work even though it is marked as bogus, automatic Windows updates will also continue to work for critical and Important updates, you just won't be able to install any extra Microsoft upgrades like newer versions of Media Player and IE for example. Check task scheduler to see if the bogus nag popup is sheduled as a task, and remove the task.

Answer (score -5):

Although this may not address your problem directly, try upgrading to [Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/buy/windows-7-home-premium.aspx).

Check you case, or the CD packet that came with you computer for a (legal) CD key.